# How can I get this Google RSS gadget to work?

Tags: rss, google-gadget

I am trying to embed an RSS feed on a web page I am designing.  The feed is for an Austin, TX Craigslist page:

http://austin.craigslist.org/search/fua?query=%22modern+salvage%22&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk=

Depending on which URL I use for the feed I get one of these results:

```
**Feed URL**

    http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?url=http://austin.craigslist.org/search/fua?query=%22modern%20salvage%22&srchType=A&format=rss

    Error parsing module spec:
    Not a properly formatted file
    missing xml header


**<link> in the XML for the above URL**

    http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?url=http://austin.craigslist.org/search/fua?query=&#x26;quot;modern%20salvage&#x26;quot;&#x26;amp;srchType=A

    Information is temporarily unavailable


**I have also tried the URL in the head of the HTML doc:**

    http://austin.craigslist.org/search/fua?query=&quot;modernsalvage&quot;&amp;srchType=A&amp;format=rss" title="RSS feed for craigslist | furniture - all &quot;&quot;modern salvage&quot;&quot; in austin

    Information is temporarily unavailable.
```

Although Craigslist encourages users to embed RSS feeds I wonder if the Craigslist server is denying the request.  I have a background in design, not programming.  Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Comment: I was able to add the feed http://montreal.en.craigslist.ca/ata/index.rss to a MyYahoo page, but was unsuccessful with Google Sites plug-in. It said it was unable to parse the feed. I can check more... Meantime, activate the Developer Tools part of your browser to see if there are any messages from Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what gadget you're using...

Anyway, I was able to make your page load with the [RSS Reader+ gadget](http://www.google.ca/ig/directory?dpos=top&root=/ig&url=www.ajaxgaier.com/iGoogle/rss-reader%2B.xml) on a [Google Sites page](https://sites.google.com/site/fuhrmanator/) (won't stay up forever).

Attempts to make it work with http://www.gstatic.com/sites-gadgets/rss-sites/rss_sites.xml were unsuccessful. I think that gadget is broken, according to comments on http://www.google.ca/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.google.com/ig/modules/reader.xml